# Wffm 8.2 form validation not working on first submit

Tags: wffm

We are running Sitecore 8.2 and WFFM 8.2 and are in the process of setting up our first form. The only save action applied is the "Send email message", which is working as intended.

The problem occurs if a user presses the 'enter' key on the form. It does not check for the *required* fields and then navigates to an unrelated URL within the site. If you then return to the form and submit again, the form submits and sends the email correctly.

It only fails to navigate to the *success* message or the *required items are missing* message if the 'enter' key is pressed anytime during filling in the form.

Nothing in the logs relating to this occurs.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Are you using MVC or WebForms?

Comment: Web forms for Marketers 8.2 update 7.

Comment: Yes, but is your solution written in MVC or ASP.Net WebForms ?

Comment: My apologies, it is written in ASP.net WebForms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was occurring due to a login input box in the header of the page. 
The JS on the page was loading in an unexpected order and was causing the enter key (id - 13) to attempt a submit on the login box instead of the webform.

This was resolved by removing the login drop-down from the header of this specific page.